# How to enable/disable attribute with config setting in bazel?

Tags: bazel

```
config_setting(
    name = "arm_cpu",
    values = {"cpu": "arm"},
)

objc_library(
    name = "a_lib",
    pch = "a.pch",
)
```

I want to make the "**pch**" attribute only take effect for arm cpu. But I don't know how to use **select**() function for label attributes easily. So I have to write an empty pch file and modify the BUILD file like this:

```
objc_library(
    name = "a_lib",
    pch = select({
        ":arm_cpu" : "a.pch",
        "//conditions:default" : "empty.pch",
    )},
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does `None` work instead of `"empty.pch"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, one can obtain the default for an attribute by using `None`:

```
objc_library(
    name = "a_lib",
    pch = select({
        ":arm_cpu" : "a.pch",
        "//conditions:default": None,
    }),
)
```